# Convert like %keyword% to Match (against)

Tags: mysql, sql

```
select col1,col2,col3,col4,col5 from table1
where (col1 like '%keyword%' 
       or col2 like '%keyword%' 
       or col3 like '%keyword%' 
       or col4 like '%keyword%' 
       or col5 like '%keyword%' )
AND start_date IS NULL 
AND end_date IS NULL 
ORDER BY date_created limit 10;
```

I want to convert the above query to use `MATCH AGAINST` function.

Comment: please try to refer this documentation first: `http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/fulltext-search.html#function_match` and see what you can try to do..

Answer (score 0):

I guell you mean sth. like that? But as @Yohanes Khosiawan stated, you could also have consulted the docs by your self.

```
SELECT col1,col2,col3,col4,col5 
FROM table1
WHERE MATCH(col1, col2, col3, col4, col5) AGAINST ('+keyword')
AND start_date IS NULL 
AND end_date IS NULL 
ORDER BY date_created limit 10;
```

Comment: Note

In implementing this feature, MySQL uses what is sometimes referred to as implied Boolean logic, in which

    + stands for AND

    - stands for NOT

    [no operator] implies OR

Comment: but from doc "+" stands for AND and "-" for NOT and "no operator" implies OR 
but i am getting wrong result set.

Comment: according to the docs, the `+` implies that the specified cells have to contain the word. if `keyword` is a simple word, the code should do what you want, otherwise, try wrapping the pattern (keyword) into additional `"` like `'"the phrase"'`, or provide additional information on the problem or where you are at right now